# Disable undo for creation/deletion of NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, undo

In my Core Data model, I've got a relationship called `listItems` which links to several `listItem` entities, each with a `stringValue` attribute. I've created a control which is essentially a list of `NSTextFields`, one for each list item. The control is bound to `listItems` properly, and I've set it up so that pressing the return key creates a new field directly under the currently-edited one and changes the focus to the new field. So, essentially, to add a new item, the user presses Return.

Likewise, if the user ends editing and the currently-edited field is empty, the field is removed (as in, empty fields only appear during "edit mode", so to speak). This works pretty well. Basically, in my `listItem` NSManagedObject subclass, I do the following:

```
// Don't allow nil values
if (!value && [[self.recipe ingredients] count] > 1) {
    for (EAIngredientRef *ingredient in [self.recipe ingredients]) {
        if ([[ingredient sortIndex] integerValue] > [[self sortIndex] integerValue]) {
            [ingredient setSortIndex:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:([[ingredient sortIndex] integerValue]-1)]];
        }
    }
    [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:self];
    return;
}

// Code to handle if it is a real value
```

The problem I am encountering is that each time a row is deleted this way, it registers with the undoManager. Thus, if I edit a row, press Return (which creates a new row), and click away to end editing, the row disappears. However, if I then undo, the empty field reappears. My goal is to have delete operations involving empty fields be ignored by the undoManager.

How would I go about this? I've tried using `[[[self managedObjectContext] undoManager] disableUndoRegistration]` and the associated `enableUndoRegistration` in several spots (such as `-didTurnIntoFault`, but I suspect that the undo registration might be happening prior to that method)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you dive more deeply into the Core Data docs, you'll find this tidbit hidden away:

```
[[self managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges];
[[[self managedObjectContext] undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];
// Do your work
[[self managedObjectContext] processPendingChanges];
[[[self managedObjectContext] undoManager] enableUndoRegistration];
```

Changes are not registered with the undo manager normally until the end of the event loop, and so were being registered *after* you'd turned undo registration back on. The above forces it to occur when you want.